# What kind of insect is this found in North America in April?

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I noticed this small insect that probably measured 5 mm in length on my coat lapel. Not sure whether or not it had been inside or landed outside on my coat. Photos were taken in Nashville, Tennessee, USA in April. It was alone and I have never seen an insect like this one before. Just trying to figure out whether this bug is harmless or something that could be a problem. [image: Small beetle?]. Here is another photo taken of the same insect.[image: Small Beetle 2]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a ladybug larva.  They eat aphids.  I have handled many and never been bitten.

https://test.whatsthatbug.com/2010/10/25/ladybird-beetle-larva-ladybug/
[image]